# Adding pectic enzyme to mead

Tags: mead

I do not have any pectic enzyme and want to start a mead batch today. Can it be added later as there is no supply distributor in my town

Comment: Pectin only exists in fruit. If you don't add any fruit to your mead, you don't need pectic enzyme

Comment: Also you can add fruit later after racking which can give you time to find the enzyme.

Answer (score 6):

If you are making mead solely from Honey, Water, Yeast, then you will not need to add anything else.  No pectic enzyme required!